# Combinations of elements in an array

Tags: c, combinations

I'm trying to write a C program to find all the combinations of an given array and a specified length. This is what I've done so far..

```
#include <stdio.h>

void com(int* a, int* t, int len, int i) {

    int j, k;

    if(len == 0) {

        for(k=0;k<3;k++) {
            printf("%d  ",t[k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    for(j = i ; j <= 4-len ; j++) {  // 4 = original array size 
        t[3-len] = a[j];
        com(a,t,len-1,i+1);
    }
}

main() {

    int t[3];
    com((int[]){4,1,3,2},&t[0],3,0); // 3 = combination length
}
```

The problem in this code is that it has no option to skip duplicates, repetitions of combination. e.g for the array {1,2,3,4} it generates

```
1  2  3  
1  2  4  
1  3  3  
1  3  4  
2  2  3  
2  2  4  
2  3  3  
2  3  4
```

but it was supposed to generate

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

What can I do for that? I'm not sure how to do that. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Also, if there is an alternative and better optimized solution than this, feel free to share.

Comment: Neither result (the actual or the wanted) is *all* combinations of length 3 from a set of 5 numbers. You probably should try out different algorithms *on paper* first, until you find one that satisfies your requirements, and then try to make a program using that algorithm.

Comment: Are you looking for all 3-element subsets of the original set?

Comment: yes, something like that @martin

Comment: And the numbers in the resulting set needs to be in *ascending* order? You should really update your question with all requirements like this.

Comment: I don't want to post a link only answer, but Rosetta code has a lot of code for algorithms like these. I think this is what you're looking for: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample to fix

```
void com(int *a, int *t, int len, int i){
    if(i == len){
        for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
            printf("%d ", t[k]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    while(*a){
        t[i] = *a;
        com(++a, t, len, i+1);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int t[3];

    com((int[]){1,2,3,4, 0}, t, 3, 0);
    //                   ^end mark
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int check(int *t)
{
  int j,k;

    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
              for(j=k+1;j<3;j++)
              {
                   if(t[k]==t[j])
                   return 0;
               }
    }
  return 1;
}

 void com(int* a, int* t, int len, int i) {

    int j, k;
    int comb=1;


    if(len == 0)
    {


     comb = check(t);

     if(comb)
      {

       for(k=0;k<3;k++) 
          {
            printf("%d  ",t[k]);
          }

        printf("\n");
       }
        return;

     }

    for(j = i ; j <= 4-len ; j++) {  // 4 = original array size

    t[3-len] = a[j];
    com(a,t,len-1,i+1);
    }
}

main() {

int t[3];
com((int[]){4,1,3,2},&t[0],3,0); // 3 = combination length
}
```

Sorry for bad editing..