# How not to print duplicate combinations in c

Tags: c

I have stored in an array a sequence of combinations for example:

{"hey", "hi", "hello"}

and I have to stamp all the combinations, for example:

1. {hey, hi, hello}
2. {hey, hey, hey}
3. {hello, hi, hi}

etc... and up to here is easy using the backtracking, but my problem is:

I cant stamp duplicate combinations like for example:

1. {hey, hi, hello}
2. {hi, hello, hey}

how you see the position of each value is different but there are the same words in these combinations.

How can I remove those duplicate combinations? Any ideas?

just to make more clear my question:

if I have this array: {"hi", "hey"}, those are the values that I can print:

1. hi, hey
2. hi, hi
3. hey, hey
4. hi
5. hey

I cant print those values:

1. hey, hi (because is already there the combination: hi, hey)

Comment: how about when you're making the combinations, storing them in a set in sorted order. So when you're making a new combination, just check if this vector exists in the set.

Comment: This `set` is defined in the c language? never heard about it

Comment: I tried but with that way other good solutions are skipped

Comment: In combinatorics terms, this is described as partitioning the integer n into a sum of m integers, where n is the number of items in each “combination” and m is the number of “combinations” in your initial sequence. (Your examples have 3 for both n and m, but they do not have to be the same in general, and your problem description does not make it clear whether they must be for your specific problem.) (Incidentally, avoid using the word “combination” for this; in contexts like this, that term is used or a different purpose in mathematics.)

Comment: Im sorry I have not found any other way to explain it better

Comment: Set up m counters in an array `C`. Design a process to iterate them: Run the first one, say `C[0]` from 0 to n, inclusive. For each value of the first one, run the second one from 0 to `n-C[0]`, inclusive. For each value of the second one, run the third one from 0 to `n-C[0]-C[1]`, inclusive. The value of the last one will be determined; it is n minus the sum of the previous values. Each set of values for these counters determines a result to be printed: Print `C[0]` instances of the first “combination”, `C[1]` of the next, and so on.

Comment: I will try to implement this in the backtracking function

Comment: what will be the maximum length of the array??

Comment: The lenght is defined at the beginning, it can be which value you want

Comment: If the maximum length of the array is n, then you just want to generate all possible combinations of length n, right?? Also, the position of the elements does not matter right?

Comment: what is the maximum value you are going to put for length in your use case?

Comment: please read again the example of my question, I cant explain better of that

Comment: rather than to find a way to remove the duplicates just do not create them, for that do not change the order of the elements

Comment: Im not create nothing, I don't just have to print them (thanks again bruno for my last question XD)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinations of elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253110/combinations-of-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: @wovano no because that time it is possible to duplicate each element

Comment: @wovano in your link it is not allowed to have 1 1 1 nor even 1 1 2 but here this is possible

Comment: Ah, okay, you're right about that @bruno (so I retracted my duplicate flag). The term "combinations" in the title was a bit misleading, IMHO, since in the classical meaning (e.g. when talking about combinations and permutations) this is different.

Comment: I dont know any other terms to define it sorry XD

Comment: @KKKKK, me neither...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose all the elements in the array are different.

To have duplicate it is needed to change the order of the elements when printing them, then to not have duplicate it is enough to let the elements in order.

A way to do can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void combine(char ** words, char ** begin, int nwords, int n2produce, int rank)
{
  if (rank == nwords-1) {
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i != nwords - n2produce; i += 1)
      printf("%s ", begin[i]);
    while (i++ != nwords)
      printf("%s ", words[rank]);
    putchar('\n');
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n2produce; i += 1) {
      begin[nwords - n2produce + i - 1] = words[rank];
      combine(words, begin, nwords, n2produce - i, rank + 1);
    }
    combine(words, begin, nwords, n2produce, rank + 1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 1) {
    char ** begin = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(*begin));
  
    combine(argv+1, begin, argc-1, argc-1, 0);
    free(begin);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze
aze 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze qsd
aze qsd 
aze aze 
qsd qsd 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze qsd wxc
aze qsd wxc 
aze qsd qsd 
aze wxc wxc 
aze aze qsd 
aze aze wxc 
aze aze aze 
qsd wxc wxc 
qsd qsd wxc 
qsd qsd qsd 
wxc wxc wxc 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach to generate your required arrays.

Consider that the new array generated will have `'x'` hellos, `'y'` his and `'z'` heys. (We are considering their counts because their position in the resultant array does not matter to us).

Now, we know the length of the array which we want to generate/find is 3.

Therefore we have,

> x+y+z=3

Now our problem is reduced to just find appropriate values of x, y and z which will satisfy the above equation.

We can easily do that using three for loops

```
for(int x=0;x<=3;++x)
{
    for(int y=0;y<=3;++y)
    {
        for(int z=0;z<=3;++z)
        {
            if(x+y+z==3)
            {
                cout<<"Hello : "<<x<<endl;
                cout<<"Hi : "<<y<<endl;
                cout<<"Hey : "<<z<<endl;
                // you will have to construct an array here,
                // I leave that task upto you
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if any part is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this solution it would never work because I use a backtracking way to solve the problem and if I change the array values with: {"hey", "hi", "hello", "bye"} 
this solution it would become obsolete. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your code is in `C++` and the question doesn't contain a `c++` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char **stack;
static int stacksize;

void combine(char *words[], int tos /* top of stack */)
{
   if (tos == stacksize) {
       for (int i = 0; i < tos; ++i)
           printf("%s%c", stack[i], i == tos - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
       return;
   }

   for (int save_tos = tos; *words; ++words, tos = save_tos)
       while (tos < stacksize) {
           stack[tos++] = *words;
           combine(words + 1, tos);
       }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stacksize = argc - 1;
    stack = malloc(stacksize * sizeof *stack);
    if (stack)
        combine(&argv[1], 0);
}
```

**Note**: The last element of the array `words` must be set to `NULL` before calling the `combine`. It is not needed in this case because `argv[argc]` is a null pointer at the program startup.

---

Test:

```
$ ./a.out aaa bbb ccc
aaa bbb ccc
aaa bbb bbb
aaa ccc ccc
aaa aaa bbb
aaa aaa ccc
aaa aaa aaa
bbb ccc ccc
bbb bbb ccc
bbb bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below will give the result you wanted:

**(It is written in Java, comment out if you need help translating it to the C language)**

**Result:**

```
hey hey hey 
hey hey hi 
hey hey hello 
hey hey 
hey hi hey 
hey hi hi 
hey hi hello 
hey hi 
hey hello hey 
hey hello hi 
hey hello hello 
hey hello 
hey 
hi hey hey 
hi hey hi 
hi hey hello 
hi hey 
hi hi hey 
hi hi hi 
hi hi hello 
hi hi 
hi hello hey 
hi hello hi 
hi hello hello 
hi hello 
hi 
hello hey hey 
hello hey hi 
hello hey hello 
hello hey 
hello hi hey 
hello hi hi 
hello hi hello 
hello hi 
hello hello hey 
hello hello hi 
hello hello hello 
hello hello 
hello
```

**Recursive "algorithm" used:**

```
public static void alg (ArrayList<String[]> result, String list [], String [] left, int current_index){
    if ( current_index == list.length ) {
        return ;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < list.length ; i ++ ){
        String [] new__list = concat(left, new String [] {list[i]});
        alg (result, list, new__list, current_index+1);

        result.add(new__list);
    }

}
```

**Entire Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    
    //concatenate 2 string arrays
    static String [] concat (String [] s1, String [] s2){
        String [] result = new String [s1.length + s2.length];
        
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i ++ ){
            if ( i < s1.length){
                result[i] = s1[i];
            }else {
                result[i] = s2 [i - s1.length];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //The algorithm
    public static void alg (ArrayList<String[]> result, String list [], String [] left, int current_index){
        if ( current_index == list.length ) {
            return ;
        }
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.length ; i ++ ){
            String [] new__list = concat(left, new String [] {list[i]});
            alg (result, list, new__list, current_index+1);
            
            result.add(new__list);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String [] list = {"hey", "hi", "hello"};
        ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList <String[]> () ;
        
        alg (result, list, new String [] {}, 0);
        
        //Print the result list
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i ++ ){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < result.get(i).length ; j ++ ){
                System.out.print(result.get(i)[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this solution is not correct, you print all the combinations even the duplicates that I dont want :(, anyway this is java my problem is on c language :'). Thanks anyway